# Visual studio List of method names in a class

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I know of the drop down list that SHOWS all the methods among many other things in a class but I am making a flow chart and for that I need a **list** as in **text** of all the methods in a class. How can I get this list because currently I am copy pasting manually the method names into a list which is so troublesome as I have 600ish methods...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Visual Studio's Refactor menu, and choose Extract Interface. [Refactor->Extract Interface on MSDN for Visual Studio 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3dyx26%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

[image]

Click button Select All, and click button OK. This will create a new file in your project for you. 
[image]

You can then copy and paste as you need.

[image]

Be sure to go back to your class and remove the interface implementation code.

Comment: I think this is a nice and quick (and dirty ;) way to do this. with a source control system, you can easily undo the changes done. So +1 by me...

Comment: i like this one too fairly simple and easy to reuse for future programs.

Comment: Is your cursor in between two methods? From MSDN: This feature is only accessible when the cursor is positioned in the class, struct, or interface that contains the members that you would like to extract.

Comment: this will not extract static or private methods

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if things have changed since the OP wrote this question, but there is a relatively easy way and that is by using Class View (Ctrl-Shift-C).  Now this solution allows all methods in a Class to be retrieved in alphabetical order by clicking on the appropriate class in the Class View and then copy-paste.

Since it is not for a whole project, only for individual classes, I suppose if you have 600 classes with 1 method each, not very appealing, but if there is a reasonable distribution of methods per class it should not be that bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to get the list of all methods, properties etc and then write them out to console or to a file.

Well for example, if you wanted to get all public static methods in a class you would do this:

```
// get all public static methods of MyClass type
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                      BindingFlags.Static);
// sort methods by name
Array.Sort(methodInfos,
        delegate(MethodInfo methodInfo1, MethodInfo methodInfo2)
        { return methodInfo1.Name.CompareTo(methodInfo2.Name); });

// write method names
foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfos)
{
  Console.WriteLine(methodInfo.Name);
}
```

Reflection is a way in which a system can query, at runtime, the types of objects and the methods and properties exposed by those objects.

In your case you don't just want all the public and static ones but all methods.  So you would make the appropriate change to the code above to get that.

Comment: "Reflection provides objects (of type Type) that encapsulate assemblies, modules and types. You can use reflection to dynamically create an instance of a type, bind the type to an existing object, or get the type from an existing object and invoke its methods or access its fields and properties. If you are using attributes in your code, Reflection enables you to access them. For more information, see Attributes." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I place that segment of code in my code and I get a lot of errors, my application is a Windows Form Application is that a problem or am I placing that code in a wrong spot? I put that code at the bottom of my code just above the last closing curly bracket

Comment: you have to use System.Reflection.  And you must place this code in a method.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely late to the party, but this is a way without messing with the code.

- Use a Disassmbly Tool like [Telerik JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx).
- Browse to and open the assembly containing your code.
- Browse to the type select the disassembly in the text window.
- With that, use a text editor like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to
  format/clean the text.